# c# default variables? Settings.Defaullt,defaultCity=txtcity.text; how to do them?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, default

Well i downloaded a program for wheater but it is not mind now, i watched, than you write a city and you close the program, and when you open it again, it has de last city you write, how is it? i watched it has this code in whaterform_formClosed
but how do i create these variables? and if this is posible can I to do a program without a database? saveing all in a dataset? or datatables? default databales? default dataset? 
but now i want to know how to create a Default variable

```
         private void weatherForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Save Settings
        Settings.Default.defaultCity = txtCity.Text;
        Settings.Default.intervalText = comboBoxEdit1.Text;
        Settings.Default.windowPosition = this.Location;
        Settings.Default.timerOn = timer1.Enabled;
        Settings.Default.intervalTime = delay;
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'settings' to do this:

> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0,
>   you can create and access values that
>   are persisted between application
>   execution sessions. These values are
>   called settings. Settings can
>   represent user preferences, or
>   valuable information the application
>   needs to use. For example, you might
>   create a series of settings that store
>   user preferences for the color scheme
>   of an application. Or you might store
>   the connection string that specifies a
>   database that your application uses.
>   Settings allow you to both persist
>   information that is critical to the
>   application outside the code, and to
>   create profiles that store the
>   preferences of individual users.

See [Using Application Settings and User Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750.aspx) for more information.

Comment: do you believe I can use a Default dataset for i dont use a database?  mmm for litle project maybe do you believe? or you dont recommend it never?

Comment: another question, all program as visual studio has this option?  mmm properties.setting? because i worked with another program and it doesn't have "properties" and you can't add a image as icon to the application, but that description can i do it? in any program? or is for visual studio only? for example, can i do, as code? or any form? thanks

Comment: The 'settings' offering from Visual Studio is simple and easy to use for small amounts of 'settings' data, so I'd recommend using that - if you need to store bigger amounts of information, then this isn't really 'settings' - this would need to be stored somewhere more suitable.

Comment: Please read the link I referred to in the answer. the articles are small and explain everything.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to store information like this is in the config file (like it is in your example)

If you open the properties of your project, it contains a tab called settings.  Add the properties that you want in there, make sure they have a scope of User and you should be able to do something very similar.